# object of type 'float' has no len()

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain

I am trying to implement an MLP in order to predict the next value of a quadratic equation, but I keep having the same problem when I am about to test the network, could you guys give me some light about it?

Error = object of type 'float' has no len()

```
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.structure import TanhLayer
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Preparing Data
dataset = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\gugub\Documents\projects\Cyrus\graph.data", header = None)
darray = np.array(dataset)

ds = SupervisedDataSet(1,1)

ds.addSample([0.2],[0.04])
ds.addSample([0.3],[0.09])
ds.addSample([0.4],[0.16])
ds.addSample([0.5],[0.25])
ds.addSample([0.6],[0.36])

#Buildin Network
net = buildNetwork(1,2,1, hiddenclass = TanhLayer)
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net,ds)
#Training Phase
for k in range(2000):
    print(trainer.train())
#Testing Phase
while True:
    e1 = float(raw_input("x >"))
    print(float(net.activate((e1))))
```

## TraceBack:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/gugub/Documents/projects/Cyrus/backprop.py', wdir='C:/Users/gugub/Documents/projects/Cyrus')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\gugub\Anaconda2\envs\Workspace\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 705, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\gugub\Anaconda2\envs\Workspace\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 87, in execfile
>       exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
>
> File "C:/Users/gugub/Documents/projects/Cyrus/backprop.py", line 28,
>   in 
>       print(float(net.activate((e1))))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\gugub\Anaconda2\envs\Workspace\lib\site-packages\pybrain\structure\networks\feedforward.py",
>   line 20, in activate
>       return super(FeedForwardNetworkComponent, self).activate(inpt)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\gugub\Anaconda2\envs\Workspace\lib\site-packages\pybrain\structure\modules\module.py",
>   line 104, in activate
>       assert len(self.inputbuffer[self.offset]) == len(inpt), str((len(self.inputbuffer[self.offset]), len(inpt)))
>
> TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: we need the full traceback in this case

Comment: Traceback Posted

Comment: [`activate`](http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/network.html#activating-a-network) expects a list, tuple, or array.  You are passing it a float.